# VBA - Detecting a cell change within the context of a macro

Tags: excel, vba, events, listener

I'm trying to create a macro that allows users to select a column and extend features of that column to other areas of the worksheet. I'm having trouble understanding how to make this work, though. The basic logic of the routine would be:

```
(1) Ask user to select column of interest
(2) Listen for cell click event
(3) Extract the features of the column chosen by the user
(4) Apply relevant features in area of the worksheet where the cell was active at the beginning of the macro
```

Is Excel capable of 'listening' for events from within a function like this? If so, how would it be implemented? Thanks.

### **UPDATE**

My goal is to create a macro that I can use in any file. The purpose of the macro is to add an additional column to a table which contains checkboxes that can be used to check off items in the table. The only thing that is throwing me off is in certain circumstances a table may have columns that are merged different from one another. For example:

```
C1    C2
1     A
1     B
2     A
```

In Excel the above table might have cells A1 and B1 merged. I want the user to have the flexibility to determine if there needs to be two checkboxes (to associate the checkboxes with column 1) or three checkboxes (to associate the checkboxes with column 2). So when the macro runs I'd like the user to be prompted to select one of the columns, and then take the merging that is observed in that column and place it in C3. Then in C3 I'll insert a checkbox in each cell associated with the table.

The code below would do the column-merge copy/pasting portion if it is known which column to copy and how many columns away from the end of the table it is. Since I want to use this macro on various tables I need to adapt it to work on the fly.

```
Sub copyMerges(sourceArea As Range, colOffset As Long)

    Dim row, col As Long
    Dim c, c2 As Range

    col = 1
    For row = 1 To sourceArea.Rows.Count
          Set c = sourceArea.cells(row, col)
          If c.MergeArea.cells.Count > 1 Then
               Set c2 = c.Offset(0, colOffset)
               If c2.MergeArea.cells.Count = 1 Then
                    c2.Resize(c.MergeArea.Rows.Count, 1).Merge
               End If
          End If
    Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use an input box set to type=8 to allow the user to select a range...  Or you can use the worksheet_selectionchange event.

Answer (score 0):

Excel-VBA is capable of performing all what you are after. But you are asking for too much and not providing anything (usually, the asker has to include a code or any kind of indication of what he/she tried and why failed).

As a rough introduction (some guidelines to help in the research/start coding/ask more precise questions process):

1. Ask user to select column of interest -> a message box (`MsgBox`).
2. Listen for cell click -> method triggered by the selection change event of the given worksheet (`Worksheet_SelectionChange` in the given `Worksheet VBA file`, that is, under `Microsoft Excel Objects`).
3. Extract the features of the column chosen by the user -> you have to get some insight into `Ranges`, more specifically `Cells`, `Rows` and `Columns`.
4. Apply relevant features in area of the worksheet where the cell was
   active at the beginning of the macro -> equivalently to the point above, you have to do some research/reading/trial-and-error on `Ranges` and how VBA interacts with cells.

------- UPDATE

`Worksheet_SelectionChange` is called every time the selection changes but your code does not need to be executed; for example, you can include something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If (Selection.Address = "cell name you want") Then
       'YOUR CODE
    End If

    'OR

    If (Selection = "the range you want") Then
       'YOUR CODE
    End If

    'ETC.

End Sub
```

I insist in the fact that these are rough indications about the right path to find the solution for your problems. You question was is it possible? The answer is: yes + some indications. But don't expect a full working code and taking care of each single detail (mainly when you haven't provided any code). I hope that everything is clearer now.

------- UPDATE AFTER YOUR QUESTION UPDATE

Now things are much clearer but still you are asking for too many things and bringing up problems more or less generic. I will give further indications on the lines of the ones above, that is, preliminary ideas helping you to start your research/coding:

- First thing I would do in your situation is thinking carefully about what I want and making sure that I cannot accomplish it a simpler way; for example: having just one macro and delivering it (the macro and, logically, the associated Excel file) and asking users to paste what they want in this file. This small change would ease things a lot.
- If you don't want to consider the alternative above, you would have to focus your research on dealing with external workbooks. The trickiest issue will be dealing with the cell-selection tracking and related event stuff. The link provided by Tim Williams will certainly help you on this front. I personally have some doubts regarding the actual reliability of this method, mainly when dealing with more than one workbook at the same time. You would have to do your research/tests, not only on the actual implementation front, but also on the reliability one (bear in mind that this is not a too common implementation and thus you will not find too much online support).
- Once the point above is tackled (you are able to access the cell-selection related events from the external workbooks), you can start focusing on the aforementioned `Ranges` and ways in which VBA communicates with cells; this time you will find plently of information in internet: codes, opinions, etc.
- You shouldn't worry at this point about the specific problems you are referring in your updated answer, once you would get a proper insight into VBA, all this will be solved pretty easily (retrieving events from external workbooks might become problematic; retrieving stored information, for example, tables and their names, is more or less easy -> on the sense of not too much information vs. lots of information).

In summary, the main problem I see in what you want is retrieving certain information from external workbooks; if you can avoid that (as proposed above, for example), this project would become really easy. In any case, you cannot come up here with a so generic question and expect an actually applicable answer. Also you have to be very clear on the exact problem and what you are looking for (in your first question, you didn't even refer the various workbooks issue).

I hope that after these (updated) starting guidelines you will be able to start to work by your own and come back here (if required) with well-delimited (and, ideally, overall-applicable, to help as much people as possible) problems.

Comment: Thanks. I'm unclear on how to implement a Worksheet_SelectionChange event for two reasons. First, I want the code to be in my Personal file so that the macro can be implemented on any worksheet, but Worksheet_SelectionChange isn't an option in the modules of the Personal file. Second, if I were to write a Worksheet_SelectionChange function to respond to a cell click wouldn't it fire any time a click is made in a worksheet? I only want it to fire in the context of the macro... I'll update my post to include code - although for the reasons mentioned above the code will be almost entirely wrong.

Comment: @tjnel I don't quite understand the my my Personal file part, but what say that being trigger every time the user makes a selection this is not the case. The function is triggered every time, but your code can be triggered only when the selected cell is the one you want. As said in my answer, this is a general reply to get you in the right direction; you have to do some research/learn. I will update this part but will not keep doing it for the other parts. Don't worry regarding your explanations, I got perfectly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to write a macro that I'd implement on many distinct excel files. If I put the VBA in my Personal.xlsx document the scope of the macro will be all of my excel files instead of just one. However, I don't know if it's possible to use the Worksheet_SelectionChange event in the Personal.xlsx file.

Comment: @tjnel (I have updated my answer, please, take a look at it) regarding what you are saying: each file containing a macro (which should be .xlsm or similar) has to deal with its own cell tracking. I am not sure how are you planning to coordinate the different macros (via text files, for example?) but whatever the way is, you can pass this information from one to the other (file 1 -> "the target cell has been clicked", information transmitted to file 2). In any case, please understand what I am writing in my answer, you should deal with everything by your own and come here for specific problems.

Comment: If you want to capture events in any open workbook then try looking at this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx

Comment: @tjnel I have quickly skimmed through the Tim Williams link and don't know what to say: never tried it and, by default, I prefer to rely on throughly-tested functionalities. Time Williams has proven me wrong in the past, so I don't know if he can do it again (= has experience on that or is just throwing up options he hasn't really tested). First thing I would do in your case is wondering if relying on different files is required at all. The higher is the number files and Excel objects and communication among them (if you bring events into the picture even worse), the less reliable. IMO.

Comment: @TimWilliams this link was for me or for the OP?

Comment: Sorry - for @tjnel.  As for "throwing up options" I haven't tested: this is a often-used and reliable approach. If you have (for example) an add-in which needs to respond to user activity then that is how you'd handle it.

Comment: @TimWilliams OK, all clear. In any case, I am not sure about the number of files the OP is expecting to deal with and about the exact reliability of this method in this situation (don't think that you use 4-5... addins and that in that case behave well). In any case, more information for the OP to help him to work on his project.

Comment: @varocarbas I want to have a macro that can work in any file, but none of those files are interacting with one another. I also need the user to specify any column and have some characteristics of that column (specifically, the way the cells in that column are merged) copied to another. There is no "correct" range from a programming standpoint; it's entirely up to the user. I'll update the main question to provide better understanding of my problem and provide sample code.

Comment: @tjnel I look forward to your update because the more you explain, the less I understand what you want exactly :)

Comment: @tjnel I saw that. I have also updated my answer. I hope that this time will be enough to close this question ("is it possible to..." -> yes, it is; + indications; + further indications to deal with external workbooks). I hope that you will find my comments useful to start the development; and, in case of finding true, well-delimited problems (without clear solution), coming back here and posting a well-defined answer which might get a proper/quick solution.